# Traversing Object to return value

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, traversal

I have a value that I am searching for. I would like to match the term I am searching for to the value of the `key` and return the value for the key of `name` associated with the same object.

Here is a sample object:

```
{
  "test1": {
    "functions": {
      "function1": {
        "inputs": [
          {
            "key": "key1",
            "name": "name1"
          },
          {
            "key": "key2",
            "name": "name3"
          },
          {
            "key": "key3",
            "name": "name3"
          }
        ]
      },
      "function2": {
        "inputs": [
          {
            "key": "key4",
            "name": "name4"
          },
          {
            "key": "key5",
            "name": "name5"
          },
          {
            "key": "key6",
            "name": "name6"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Let's say I want to find the `name` of an input with a `key` of `key4`. How would I achieve this in javascript?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: You can use `Object.keys()` or the more recent `Object.entries()` to iterate object keys or key/value pairs respectively. (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) See the difference between `in` and `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty()` for a caveat regarding that.  For arrays, `Array.prototype.filter()` or `Array.prototype.find()` should give you that part of things. (Used in combination with `Object.keys()`/`Object.entries()`, as well.)

Answer (score 1):

You only have to iterate the individual objects inside of the `"inputs"` array and check, whether the key property is "key4"

```
var inputs = []; // you would have to get the individual lists
inputs.forEach(function (input) {
    if (input['key'] === 'key4') {
        // do something with input['name'];
    }
});
```

optimally you would make a function, that returns the `input['name']`